# Unable to change mouse sensitivity

Tags: debian, mouse, xinput, settings

**System**: Debian 11 Bullseye 
**DE**: XFCE or KDE

There is only an acceleration slider in the mouse settings (acceleration only).

And no acceleration profile or mode flags in **xinput**. Acceleration flags i have:

```
libinput Accel Speed (301): 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (302): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (303): 1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (304): 1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (305): 1, 0
```

If I disable acceleration with xinput, I can't be able to change the sensitivity at all. Changing the DPI is not an option.

I have several different mouses - same result.

**xset** output:

```
> xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  20
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 0    Off: 900
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Comment: I've seen this answer. As I said, I don't have the "AccelerationProfile" and "AccelerationScheme" flags.

Comment: Is it better now? Now you can help?

Comment: These lines? Nothing more about the mouse input.

Comment: It would be great to completely disable acceleration and increase speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I realized that libinput has different acceleration props:

```
libinput Accel Profiles Available
  2 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "adaptive", "flat". Indicates which acceleration profiles are available on this device.
libinput Accel Profile Enabled
  2 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "adaptive", "flat". Indicates which acceleration profile is currently enabled on this device.
```

So, I can disable acceleration (enable flat profile) with:

```
xinput --set-prop 8 304 0, 1
```

Where **8** is my mouse id and **304** is *"libinput Accel Profile Enabled"* property.

Now I can control sensitivity by changing *"libinput Accel Speed"* flag.

Answer (score 0):

From OP *(prior to your first edit)* you ran `xinput --list-props "Logitech G502 Hero Gaming Mouse"` in terminal. You show us only part of the corresponding output, e.g. without the X11 numeric device id ("xid") for the pointer of interest. You can get it with:

```
 $ xid = "$(xinput --list --id-only 'Logitech G502 Hero Gaming Mouse')"
```

According to Xorg [doc](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml), command `xinput --list-props "Logitech G502..."` list properties that can be set for a device. In your case the only enabled acceleration profile is the *"device-dependent"* profile "1". The only profile listed as available is also `1`, so I am not certain that changing the profile to something else will be effective.  But you can experiment by trying to change it to `5` for instance, which is documented by Xorg as a *power law acceleration profile*. To do so:

```
$ xinput --set-prop "$xid" 303 5, 1
```

To modify mouse speed and acceleration see [this](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading8) and [`man xinput`](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml) and try, either:

```
$ xset mouse 5/1 0
```

or:

```
$ xinput --set-prop "$xid" 301 5   # for Accel Speed
```

The `xset ...` command above is meant to increase pointer acceleration by a factor 2.5 and nullify the threshold at which acceleration kicks in. The above may or may not be what you need to do in your case though. Just try ! The *simple* and *limited* profiles (respectively with profile ids `4` and `7`) use it directly (i.e. they accelerate by the given ratio). If specifying an acceleration profile of `5` does not produce the expected results, replace `5` by `4` or by `7`.

If your tweaks do not give you satisfaction, you can either reverse all the change manually one by one. or simply reboot, which will wipe all tweaks and return setting to default.
On the contrary, if your tweaks give you satisfaction, you can make them permanent across reboots following this past [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/794420/292181) of mine. 
 In any case access to your hardware is needed to experiment, so you will have to do that on your side and there is not much more I can do.  HTH.

---

***Note:***
You will see posts mentioning the 3x3 CTM (see "[Coordinate transformation matrix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation)"), which by default is set to the identity matrix `1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0` as in your case) as being one of the properties to tweak to change pointer speed. This is neither correct, nor will it modify speed as you need.